# Problema con codigo PHP

Tags: php, sql

Tengo un codigo que me deberia mostrar ciertos datos de a cuerdo a la fecha que el usuario envia por fomrulario, es decir, necesito que se me muestren una cierta cantidad de pedidos en un rango de fechas determinado pero resulta que la tabla que se me muestra esta vacia, adjunto codigo de formulario y el que realiza la accion:

```
<html>
<body style="background-color:#47D4A2;">
<h1 align=center> Tomy Resfrescos S.A</h1>
<h2> Listados de pedidos </h2>
<h4> Ingrese rango de fechas: </h4>
<form action="http://localhost/prueba/ResultadoDePedidos.php"   method="GET"id="formulario">    
Fecha inicial:<input  name="fecha1" type="date">
<br>
Fecha final:<input name="fecha2" type="date">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="continuar"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

y este es el otro:

```
<?php
include("conexion.php");
$fecha1=$_GET['fecha1'];
$fecha2=$_GET['fecha2'];
$link=Conectarse();
$result=mysql_query("SELECT num_ped,fec_rep FROM pedidos WHERE fec_rep>= 
$fecha1 AND fec_rep<= $fecha2",$link);
?>                  
<TABLE BORDER=1 CELLSPACING=1
CELLPADDING=1>
<TR><TD>&nbsp;Numero de Pedido</TD><TD>&nbsp;Fecha de Entrega&nbsp;</TD> </TR>
<?php
while($row= mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
printf("<tr>
<td>&nbsp;%s</td>
<td>&nbsp;%s&nbsp;</td>
</tr>",
$row["0"],$row["1"]);
}
mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close($link);
?>  
</table> 
</body>
</html>
```

El problema es que se muestra la tabla con los nombres de las columnas, la conexion es exitosa pero la tabla esta vacia y no entiendo porque.

Comment: de que tipo es fec_rep?

Comment: ¿En qué formato envías las fechas? ¿yyyy/mm/dd?

Comment: las fecha fec_rep es formato date y la fecha se envia como dd/mm/yyyy, no se como podria cambiar el formato

Comment: sebastian, puedes agregar en que formato se encuentran las fechas en la base de datos?

Answer (score 0):

Modifica tu archivo php con este código, con esto se debería de solucionar, y te recomiendo que utilices el método `POST`, es mas seguro que `GET`:

```
<?php
include("conexion.php");
$fecha1=$_GET['fecha1'];
$fecha2=$_GET['fecha2'];
$link=Conectarse();
$result=mysql_query("SELECT num_ped,fec_rep FROM pedidos WHERE fec_rep BETWEEN '$fecha1' AND '$fecha2' ",$link);
?>  

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>                
<TABLE BORDER=1 CELLSPACING=1 CELLPADDING=1>
<TR>
<TD>&nbsp;Numero de Pedido</TD>
<TD>&nbsp;Fecha de Entrega&nbsp;</TD> 
</TR>
<?php

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
echo "<tr>
<td>'".$row[0]."'</td>
<td>'".$row[1]."'</td>
</tr>";
                    } 

mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close($link);
?>  
</table> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías detallar los cambios que hiciste y explicar el por qué?

Answer (score 0):

Intenta cambiar tu consulta de esta forma:

```
SELECT num_ped,fec_rep FROM pedidos WHERE fec_rep >= STR_TO_DATE($fecha1, '%d/%m/%Y') AND fec_rep <= STR_TO_DATE($fecha2, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

si estas usando MYSQL el formato por defecto de la fecha es YYYY-MM-DD y el formato que en que estas enviando la fecha que envías es dd/mm/yyyy por lo que la tienes que cambiar el formato. Si estas usando algún calendario para la selección de la fecha le puedes cambiar ahí el formato sino cambia el formato de la fecha desde php Ej:

```
$a_fecha1 = explode("/",$fecha1);
$ffecha1 = $a_fecha1[2]."-".$a_fecha1[1]."-".$a_fecha1[0]
```